# How to manage indexeddb in React

Tags: reactjs, indexeddb

I am trying to use indexeddb (via [idb](https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb) as a promise wrapper) in a react component. I am managing the connections with `useEffect`, but I keep struggling with this:

```
const Component = () => {
  const [database, setDatabase] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    /* to use async in `useEfect` I have to move it to its own fn */
    const getDatabase = async () => {
      const db = await openDB("my-db", 1, {
        upgrade(db) {
          db.createObjectStore("my-store");
        }
      });
      setDatabase(db);
    };

    getDatabase();
    return () => database.close();
  }, []);
  return null;
};
```

But if the component amounts and

```
database.close()
```

get's called, the `database` state is undefined and it breaks:
Codesandbox [Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/little-lake-lls0r?fontsize=14).
Apparently this is [by design](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14066#issuecomment-435458108).

I found one ugly workaround where I use `_database` to store the latest database.

```
const Component = () => {
  const [database, setDatabase] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    /* to use async in `useEfect` I have to move it to its own fn */
    let _database
    const getDatabase = async () => {
      const db = await openDB("my-db", 1, {
        upgrade(db) {
          db.createObjectStore("my-store");
        }
      });
      setDatabase(db);
      _database = db
    };

    getDatabase();
    return () => _database.close();
  }, []);
  return null;
};
```

But that does not seem right. What is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: Hi, check this out: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-indexed-db

Answer (score 1):

Your workaround isn't the worst thing in the world, I think. But I also think there is still a race condition if the component is unmounted after `openDB` has been called but before the promise resolves, in which case `_database` will be undefined in the cleanup function. I think you could do something like this to handle that scenario:

```
const Component = () => {
  const [database, setDatabase] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    let _database, closed;
    const getDatabase = async () => {
      const db = await openDB("my-db", 1, {
        upgrade(db) {
          db.createObjectStore("my-store");
        }
      });
      if (closed) {
        db.close();
      } else {
        setDatabase(db);
        _database = db
      }
    };

    getDatabase();
    return () => {
      if (_database) {
        _database.close();
      }
      closed = true;
    }
  }, []);
  return null;
};
```

I agree that is not the nicest looking code in the world. So it goes with IndexedDB much of the time.

Personally, what I do when using React and IndexedDB is connect to the database before calling `ReactDOM.render`, and store that connection outside of React. Then I can just use it as I please without worrying about how it relates to the React component lifecycle. However I don't think there's inherently anything wrong with putting it in some wrapper React component. You just have to be careful. But hey, it's IndexedDB, you gotta be careful anyway :)

Answer (score -1):

```
const useIndexedDB = (dbName: string, storeName: string, keyPath: string) => {
  const [db, setDb] = useState<IDBDatabase | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (window === undefined) {
      return;
    }
    const openDb = async () => {
      const request = window.indexedDB.open(dbName, 1);
      request.onupgradeneeded = (event) => {
        if (!event.target) {
          return;
        }
        // @ts-ignore
        const db = event.target.result as IDBDatabase;
        db.createObjectStore(storeName, { keyPath });
      };
      request.onsuccess = (event) => {
        if (!event.target) {
          return;
        }
        // @ts-ignore
        const db = event.target.result as IDBDatabase;
        setDb(db);
      };
    };
    openDb();
  }, []);

  const add = async (data: any) => {
    if (!db) {
      return;
    }
    const transaction = db.transaction(storeName, "readwrite");
    const store = transaction.objectStore(storeName);
    store.add(data);
    return transaction.oncomplete;
  };

  const get = async (key: string) => {
    if (!db) {
      return;
    }
    const transaction = db.transaction(storeName, "readonly");
    const store = transaction.objectStore(storeName);
    return store.get(key);
  };

  const getAll = async () => {
    if (!db) {
      return;
    }
    const transaction = db.transaction(storeName, "readonly");
    const store = transaction.objectStore(storeName);
    return store.getAll();
  };

  const deleteItem = async (key: string) => {
    if (!db) {
      return;
    }
    const transaction = db.transaction(storeName, "readwrite");
    const store = transaction.objectStore(storeName);
    store.delete(key);
    return transaction.oncomplete;
  };

  return { add, get, getAll, deleteItem };
};
```

It looks like you've created a custom React hook named useIndexedDB that provides basic functionality for interacting with IndexedDB, a browser-based database. This hook initializes and manages the IndexedDB connection and exposes functions to perform common operations like adding data, retrieving data by key, retrieving all data, and deleting items.

```
 const [inputData, setInputData] = useState('');
  const { add, get, getAll, deleteItem } = useIndexedDB('myDatabase', 'myStore', 'id');

  const handleAdd = async () => {
    if (inputData.trim() === '') return;

    const data = {
      id: Date.now().toString(),
      value: inputData.trim(),
    };

    await add(data);
    setInputData('');
  };

  const handleGet = async () => {
    const key = prompt('Enter the key to retrieve data:');
    if (!key) return;

    const result = await get(key);
    alert(result ? `Value for key ${key}: ${result.value}` : 'Key not found');
  };

  const handleGetAll = async () => {
    const result = await getAll();
    alert(result ? `All data: ${JSON.stringify(result)}` : 'No data found');
  };

  const handleDelete = async () => {
    const key = prompt('Enter the key to delete:');
    if (!key) return;

    await deleteItem(key);
    alert(`Item with key ${key} deleted`);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={inputData}
        onChange={(e) => setInputData(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Enter data"
      />
      <button onClick={handleAdd}>Add Data</button>
      <button onClick={handleGet}>Get Data</button>
      <button onClick={handleGetAll}>Get All Data</button>
      <button onClick={handleDelete}>Delete Data</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```